# Can anyone explain DBOS to me?

Tags: operating-system

I have read on DBOS a bit and I don't get it. How the hell is this an OS? I mean, from what I gather, it's an application (in nodejs) that runs on top of some Linux (Ubuntu, Alpine, whatever). How is that an OS? I fail to understand how/what it should be used for so any explanations about this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no formal definition of an "operating system" ... so you would need to debate that with the people who invented the name.  But your question is off-topic as this is not about Programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBOS is built on top of a Linux kernel and provides a minimalistic, containerized environment for running Node.js applications. It's designed to be a fast, efficient, and secure way to deploy web applications, especially those built using modern technologies like Node.js, React, and GraphQL.
DBOS is not meant to replace traditional operating systems, but rather to provide a specialized environment for running specific types of applications. It's like a Swiss Army knife for web developers - it's not a replacement for a full-fledged operating system, but it's great for quickly deploying and managing web applications.